# Text cleaning: removing dates from text, where there are

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I would need to clean some text which may contain a sequence like this:

```
Date            Text
2020-06-01  1 giu 2020 - Per farlo hai messo in atto un pia...
2020-06-01  La trappola del Paragone
2020-06-05  5 giu 2020 - sistema Aegis Ashore? N...
2020-06-05  Lewis Hamilton - «Il silenzio colpevole della F1»
```

There might be texts which starts with a date (format `1 giu 2020`, i.e. d m yyyy, followed by `-`) and texts which do not.
I would like to know how to keep only the part of text, i.e.

```
Date            Text
2020-06-01  Per farlo hai messo in atto un pia...
2020-06-01  La trappola del Paragone
2020-06-05  sistema Aegis Ashore? N...
2020-06-05  Lewis Hamilton - «Il silenzio colpevole della F1»
```

I have tried as follows:

`fil_dataset['Text']=fil_dataset['Text'].str.split(n=4).str[-1]`  but does not work as it can remove also part of text. A possible solution, proposed by anky in his/her comment below, unfortunately does not work as well, as I need also to keep in mind that there might be a `-`, which does not follow a date, that could remove some text.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `df['Text'].str.split('-').str[-1]`..?

Comment: @anky. The problem is that if there is another -, which does not follow a date, it will remove the text.

Comment: I would like to know why this question was down-voted and also voted for being closed. I think I followed all the guidelines within this community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.replace`:

```
print (df["Text"].str.replace("\d{1,2}\s\w*\s\d{4}\s-\s",""))

0                Per farlo hai messo in atto un pia...
1                             La trappola del Paragone
2                           sistema Aegis Ashore? N...
3    Lewis Hamilton - «Il silenzio colpevole della F1»
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regexp like `r'\d{1,2} (giu|mai|abc|xyz) 20\d\d '`, with other Italian(?) month abbreviations inserted.

I don't recall off hand how to apply this as a filter in Pandas but hopefully you can work that out.